# Detecting unknown XML tags in Scala

Tags: xml, scala, defensive-programming

I'm building an XML parser in Scala and want to be defensive against user mistakes. If the user gives a tag that I don't support (e.g., `<named>` rather than `<name>`) or, more generally, puts a tag in the wrong place, I want to detect it and throw an error. How do I do this the Scala way?

Comment: If you have XSD for your XML you can use http://scalaxb.org to generate object model + parsers + validation

Comment: Is that an [XML schema?](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/)

Comment: yes. I think that creating schema for your xml is a right way to go

Comment: Can you give a description of using the scalaxb.org tool as an answer? If it works, I can give you a big 'ol checkmark. :D

Comment: 'scalaxb [options] <schema_file>' to generate scala code from schema. Later you can use something like this: scalaxb.fromXML[MyDomainObject] and id xml doesn't fit into schema you'll get an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best suggestion I have received thus far is to build an XML schema and use that to validate the file. w3schools show how to build a schema [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_example.asp). There exists a variety of tools and classes that use these schemas to validate XML. I hope to update  this answer soon with the approach I find works most elegantly!